# A wireframing tool to design Windows 8/8.1 applications

Tags: gratis, gui, user-interface, wireframing

I want to design a Windows 8/8.1 desktop application. Before going into the coding part, I want to create a mockup of the same. Balsamiq would satisfy my need to some extent, but I need something on the lines of [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn), wherein one could drag and drop stuff into the frame to create a compete design.

Issue with Balsamiq: It offers no special help while creating a Windows app. In Pencil, you could drag/drop a notification-bar, a button etc. (Android) and the app can be made to look exactly as it would after completion.

I’d like a solution for Windows or Linux. A cross-platform tool would be a bonus, though not very necessary.

Comment: So the wireframing tool is also required to *run* on Windows 8, correct?

Comment: Windows or Linux would do

Comment: So what's wrong with Pencil then?

Comment: Pencil isn't really for Windows-style applications.

Answer (score 2):

What about [Microsoft Project Siena](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/projectsiena/default.aspx)?

[image]

It is supposed to be rapid development tool for simple Modern UI apps.

After you start, the first thing you are supposed to do is to draw some UI. This looked to me useful for prototyping. UI drawing process is assisted by guides so you can align controls quickly.
Going further, you can even arrange multiple screens and use kind of "Go To" action to move between them. And all the time in preview mode you have all controls live (because you actually created an application) so for example you can scroll image lists.

To me it looked **quite useful for UI layout prototyping** although it is targeted for more: creation of simple apps.

Comment: This is not or no longer gratis. I has a monthly payment of at least 5 USD.

Comment: @ThomasWeller – I wonder whether this unavailability in 2021 was a reason for down voting the answer written in 2014.

Comment: Yes, I confess. I came here because I was looking for a gratis wireframe tool - I spent almost 30 minutes on it and it doesn't suit my needs. That's what I consider "not useful" and that's exactly what the downvote is supposed to indicate.